# saving values of sound in android

Tags: android

I have developed an android game application.I want to save the values of sound like we save the value like name,email using shared preference.How can we keep the value of a variable saved even after app is terminated in android app?

I have uploaded my app on http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/301549/RoadTrip1-rar.html Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Regards Tushar

Comment: What kind of values your sound have? Are you trying to save sound files in `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you?

Simply save the reference to the sound resource to the SharedPreferences.

If you want to save recorded sound you should save it to the SD Card.